# Is it possible to create a shortcut to my actions google assistant within an app?

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, google-assistant-sdk

I am creating an app with a feature that allows the user to interact with a chatbot (google assistant made with dialogflow and actions google). I am wondering if these two options are possible:

**- Creating a button in the app that opens Google Assistant**:
I've tried to find the URI for google assistant and it doesn't seem to work for me

**- Creating a shortcut in my iOS/Android device that will connect me with my google assistant directly**:
I'd like to avoid the user having to make the mistake of talking to google assistant and not being able to access the assistant I made. This would also help if creating a button is not possible.

Preferably, it'd be nice to have both options. Please let me know if you have any suggestions or ideas, I'd appreciate it! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

In the Actions Console you should be able to see, under the Deploy Tab, a section for Assistant Links. Going through the to get a generated URL that will open up directly into the Assistant app to your Action. You can also add additional deep linking capability like opening to a specific intent.

A screenshot is below.

[image]

Comment: I am unable to see a generated URL, instead it shows "Assistant Links are not enabled for this intent in en language. You can enable it here." When I click 'here' I don't see where I can enable something. Have you had this problem? Thank you for your response by the way!

Comment: Which intent are you trying to use? Is it the `actions.intent.MAIN` or another intent that is invokable?

Comment: I noticed that I do not have the option because I did not migrate to actions google. Is that the case for you? You migrated or built your conversation in actions google instead of dialogflow? @nick felker

Comment: This example in particular is for Actions Builder.